# Unable to send email using Java API

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send email via JavaMain API but getting read timeout exceptio.

Configurations I did ::

I have imported below dependencies in my gradle project ::

```
implementation("javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.2")
implementation("com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.2")
implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-email:1.5")
```

And Java code ::

```
System.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "50000"); // Set socket connection timeout to 5 seconds
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.timeout", "50000"); // Set socket I/O timeout to 5 seconds

        // Email authentication credentials
        String username = "myUsername@....";
        String password = "mypassword";

        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

            // Create MimeMessage object
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            // Set sender
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sender@example.com"));
            // Set recipient
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("receiver@test.com"));
            // Set subject
            message.setSubject("Test Email");
            // Set message body
            message.setText("This is a test email sent using JavaMail API.");

            // Create Transport object and send message
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect();
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
         } Catch (Exception e){
         }
```

Error getting ::

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Can someone please help if I am missing anything in above code ?

Comment: Are you allowed to connect to that host?

Comment: @g00se , yeah ping smtp.gmail.com is working fine from my local

Comment: Yes but that's not definitive. Try telnetting to it